# Tabulator and Context Menu double right click issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, contextmenu, tabulator

I'm using Tabulator 4.5 and I wrote an headerContext callback function in order to set and display a context menu on the fly (using contextMenu.js).
The issue is that the context menu appears only if I right click the header title twice, let me explain:

- Page Loads
- Right click on "Name" header column
- On the first right click my custom handler function is correctly called (confirmed by the console.log output messages) but no context menu is displayed.
- On the second right the context menu is correctly displayed.
  Any following right clicks work as expected.

This is the JS code:

```
let tabledata = [
  {"name": "Bob", "email": "bob@somewhere.com"},
  {"name": "Ben", "email": "ben@somewhere.com"},
  {"name": "Ted", "email": "ted@somewhere.com"}                
]


function customHeaderContext(e, column) {
  console.log("Header Context handler triggered!")
  e.preventDefault();
  let element = column.getElement();
  $(element).contextMenu({
    selector: '.tabulator-col-content',
    build: function($triggerElement, e) {
      console.log("Trigger element:", $triggerElement);

      return {
        callback: function(key, options) {
          console.log("Callback called with selection:", key);
          console.log("Callback called with options:", options);
        },
        items: {
          "cut": {name: "Cut Option", icon: "cut"},
          "copy": {name: "Cut Option", icon: "copy"},
        } // end items
      }  // end return
    } // end build
  });  // end contextmenu def
}


var table = new Tabulator("#example-table-1", {
  //height:211,
  layout:"fitColumns",
  data:tabledata,
  columns:[
    {title:"Name", field:"name", headerContext:customHeaderContext},
    {title:"Email", field:"email"},
  ],
});
```

I know I could use the contextMenu.js embedded event handling, but I'd like to keep the Tabulator one because I need to access data contained in the columns where the right click occurred.

I wrote an example Codepen reproducing the issue.
https://codepen.io/giplusplus/pen/mdJrjqw

Where I am doing wrong?

Thank you all!

Comment: Try using context menu without Jquery

Comment: @dota2pro What do you mean by "using context menu without Jquery" ?

Answer (score 2):

Version 4.6 was released at the end of March 2020 and now contains built in [Context Menus](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.6/menu)

```js
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    rowContextMenu: [
        {
            label:"Hide Column",
            action:function(e, column){
                column.hide();
            }
        },
        {
            separator:true,
        },
        {
            disabled:true,
            label:"Move Column",
            action:function(e, column){
                column.move("col");
            }
        }
    ]
});
```